# Cache in Azure Front door service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-front-door

I have setup azure front door service for three different geographies. The users are getting routed to the nearest data centre which is working as expected. Currently, I am setting up Caching under routing rules. I need to exclude some of the files that need not be cached. I do not see any configuration which allows exclude caching from certain files.

Below is the screenshot of the configuration setting.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHaEr.jpg

Answer (score 3):

While I think Nancy Xiong answer would work, I don't think this the correct approach.

Azure Front Door respects `Cache-Control` headers, therefore make sure your web server that is serving the files you don't want to cache returns a proper value. A decent starting point might be `Cache-Control: no-cache`, but check out the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) for the details and options.

And talking about Azure Front Door - it claims that it respects these values ([docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-caching#cache-expiration)):

> Cache-Control response headers that indicate that the response won’t be cached such as Cache-Control: private, Cache-Control: no-cache, and Cache-Control: no-store are honored. However, if there are multiple requests in-flight at a POP for the same URL, they may share the response. If no Cache-Control is present the default behavior is that AFD will cache the resource for X amount of time where X is randomly picked between 1 to 3 days.

Answer (score 1):

Since Azure front door matches the request to and then takes the defined action according to the particular routing rules. So if you need to exclude some of the files that do not be cached, you could try to create a separate routing rule with **PATTERNS TO MATCH** to set to the path of specific no-need-to cached files. Then set `disabled` caching in the **ROUTE DETAILS** in this separate routing rule.

Ref: [How Front Door matches requests to a routing rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-route-matching)